# Steam wont open on ubuntu 20.04.2, not displaying error messages

Tags: apt, steam

I installed Steam on Ubuntu 20.04.2 (using cinnamon as desktop theme). I did it by `sudo apt-get install steam` and then wrote steam to launch it. It worked fine the first time. However, after restarting my PC, it didn't work anymore. I uninstalled it by `sudo apt-get remove steam` and installed again, but it did not work.

When I try to click it from the graphical app menu (start menu) nothing simply happens. When I write steam in terminal, I get this output:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 20.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Steam runtime environment up-to-date!
Steam client's requirements are satisfied
WARNING: Using default/fallback debugger launch
/home/user/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/steam -nominidumps -nobreakpad
```

And nothing happens, the terminal just returns to normal state.

Comment: have you enabled 32-bit/i386 arch on your system? `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`

Comment: @nobody running that command prints "i386". Also, like I said, steam worked fine once, but after restarting PC it stopped working (and reinstalling did not make it work again)

Comment: I installed a .deb package from [here](https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/)
It managed to launch steam again, but I will see if it runs a second time and report here

Comment: Installing the .deb package from the link in my previous comment solved the issue. However, I still have no idea why it only worked the first time when installing via apt-get.